# when commit is being made on MQ connection when the queue manager is not transacted?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, mq

when commit is being made on IBM MQ connection, when the connection is not transacted ?
I'm configuring JMS Transactions in Camel 2.10.4 routes and my application is the consumer and producer .
I need to read from  a queue and then write to other queue.I must be sure that the read connection is close before writing to the other queue. 
The relevant sections in my application context XML config file is shown:

```
<bean id="jmsConfig" 
   class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
   <property name="transacted" value="false" />

</bean>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Commit(MQCMIT) indicates to the queue manager that the application has reached a syncpoint, it occurs only after successful completion of MQGET, MQPUT1 and MQPUT.

So in your case when you are trying to read the Messages from the queue, below API calls occur in the below order

```
MQCONN
MQOPEN
MQGET
MQCLOSE
MQDISC
```

After this, commit happens.  messages retrieved as part of a unit of work are deleted.

In the case of placing the messages on to a below API calls will occur

```
MQCONN, MQPUT1, MQDISC.
```

Later, commit occurs. messages which are placed as part of a unit of work are made available to other applications.

In your case you are using one application for both read and write. An application will not be relieved from the action until it closes the connections in mannerly fashioned. During unavoidable conditions, messages will rollback if commit is not happening.

Comment: as I said I'm configuring  JMS  with spring and Camel 2.10.4 . Camel inject the incoming message to : process(Exchange exchange) method in  Processor interface . My question is : does commit has bean already made at this point ?